# Prefix reference id does not work as expected

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to separate my bibliography from the general bibliography. I want something like `[MINE1] XXX` for me and `[1] YYY` for others.

So far I've the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[autolang=other,style=numeric,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt,maxbibnames=100,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@ARTICLE{Sun,
author={Yanhua Sun and Yick-Sing Ho and Lie Yu},
journal={IEEE Transactions on Magnetics},
title={Dynamic Stiffnesses of Active Magnetic Thrust Bearing Including Eddy-Current Effects},
year={2009},
month={Jan},
volume={45},
number={1},
keywords={mine},
}
@book{Moon,
  title={Field Theory Handbook},
  author={Moon, P. and Spencer, D.E.},
  year={1961},
  location={Berlin, Heidelberg},
  publisher={Springer}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

This is me~\cite{Sun}.

This is not me~\cite{Moon}.

My bibliography is:

\begin{refsection}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[keyword=mine,resetnumbers=true,prefixnumbers=MINE,heading=none]

\end{refsection}

Other guys bibliographies:

% others refs
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true,notkeyword=mine,heading=none]

\end{document}
```

But It does not work as expected, as my citation uses a number and not the prefix:

[image: Results]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your approach was that a `refsection` is local, as such its references are not accessible from outside that `refsection`, so when you cited `Sun` in the document you were (for `biblatex` at least) citing `Sun` in a "global" bibliography and not the `Sun` in the local `refsection`.
`biblatex` also has `refsegments` that are "more global versions" of `refsection`s, but I don't think we will actually need those.

It should be enough to just let your bibliography be

```
\printbibliography[keyword=mine,prefixnumbers=MINE,heading=none]
```

while the one for others is

```
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true,notkeyword=mine,heading=none]
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,defernumbers=true,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Sun,
author={Yanhua Sun and Yick-Sing Ho and Lie Yu},
journal={IEEE Transactions on Magnetics},
title={Dynamic Stiffnesses of Active Magnetic Thrust Bearing Including Eddy-Current Effects},
year={2009},
month={Jan},
volume={45},
number={1},
keywords={mine},
}
@ARTICLE{Sun2,
author={Yanhua Sun and Yick-Sing Ho and Lie Yu},
journal={Journal of Articles},
title={A Second Article by Yours Truly},
year={2010},
month={Feb},
volume={46},
number={2},
keywords={mine},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
This is me \cite{Sun} and \cite{Sun2}.
This is not me \cite{wilde,cicero}.

My bibliography is:
\printbibliography[keyword=mine,prefixnumbers=MINE,heading=none]

Other guys bibliographies:
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true,notkeyword=mine,heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]